# Finding the distribution of $Y_2$,knowing that $Y_1 \in Po(\lambda/2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The random variables $N,X_1,X_2..$ are independent, $N\in Po(\lambda)$, and $X_k \in B(1/2) , k \geq 1$ Set.

$Y_1 =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}X_k $ and $Y_2 = N - Y_1$.

Determine the  distributions of $Y_1,Y_2$.

So, i have found that $Y_1 \in P(\lambda/2)$. However i have difficulties with $Y_2$.

Here is were I am.

$P(Y_2 = k \mid N = n) = P(n-Y_1 = k \mid N = n)  = P(Y_1 = n-k \mid N =n) = e^{-\lambda/2} \dfrac{(\lambda/2)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} $.

furthermore:

$P(Y_2 = k) = \sum\limits_{n=k}^{\infty} P(Y_2 = k \mid N = n)P(N =n) =\sum\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}  e^{-\lambda/2} \dfrac{(\lambda/2)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \cdot e^{-\lambda}\dfrac{\lambda^n}{n!}$

Actually i know that $Y_2 \in P(\lambda/2)$ but i don't that from the last sum. Did i do any mistakes in my calculation of $P(Y_2 = k)$ ? ?

Comment: Mistake: $P(Y_2=k∣N=n)=P(n−Y_1=k)$ is wrong.

Comment: @Did why is that wrong? could you explain

Comment: now i changed it ..

Comment: oh i see the problem $P(Y_1 = k \mid N = n) \in bin(n,1/2)$

Comment: Yes, binomial, not Poisson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to find the distribution of $Y_1$, you must be willing to notice that
$$Y_2 = \sum_{k=1}^N(1-X_k)$$
where $1-X_k$'s are again $B(1/2)$.

Comment: this approach was much easier then the one i tried

Comment: @Danny yeah, a small observation allows to simplify :)